# How many master node we can create in Single Server using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Hi I am implementing an Email Client Application. My application going to deal 10000 * 10000 of records. so for scalability purpose, i prefered cluster Concept from Nodejs. so my requirement is for every 1000 Process should be handled by one master Node with help of its Workers. so i got question like, in Single Server How many Master Node can be allowed. if any one know pls let me know.... Waiting for reply....

Master 1 -> should handle 1000 of Records 
 4 Workers (At a time 4 Record can be processed if CPU core is 4)

Master 2 -> should handle 1000 of Records 
 4 Workers (At a time 4 Record can be processed if CPU core is 4)

like above i need to handle...

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 1. Nodejs scales nice for one CPU and to use more CPUs you have the workers. You also can't share the ports, so how would the email clients know how to connect to additional masters?